# Stack push notifications with Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've developed and Android app that receives Push Notifications using Firebase. My code is based on Firebase/Google official docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client and https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) and has nothing special, it has the service that extends FirebaseMessagingService and the service that extends FirebaseInstanceIdService. Everything is working ok.

But this app is receiving more notifications than expected and my client wants the app to stack the notifications it receives. 
I've seen tutorials with the solution working over the old GCM mechanism but nothing with FCM. So my doubts are:
is possible to stack received push notifications with FCM? or has this to be somehow coded in the backend?

Comment: This is my issue too. Really looking forward for someone from Firebase team to clarify the topic

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You just need to add `.setGroup(GROUP_KEY_XPTO)` to your notification builder. All the notifications with the same group id will be stacked.

```
final static String GROUP_KEY_EMAILS = "group_key_emails";

// Build the notification, setting the group appropriately
Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender1)
         .setContentText(subject1)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
         .build();

// Issue the notification
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId1, notif);
```

On the next notification:

```
Notification notif2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender2)
         .setContentText(subject2)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
         .build();

notificationManager.notify(notificationId2, notif2);
```

See more about it here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html

Comment: That is the solution I've found so far but I'm not sure if it's valid for Firebase. In my code I don't have any call to NotificationCompat.Builder. Following the Firebase tutorial you don't need to have it.

Comment: Override `onMessageReceived`. You need to follow this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: But this method is only called if the app is in the foreground (and in that case I don't need to stack the notifications). With Firebase, if the app is closed or in the background the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray and is there where the notifications are shown one by one, how could I stack them there if my app is not running?

Comment: For that I think you need to use data messages: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: But then, this implies that some changes have to be made in the backend code, no?

Comment: Yes, the body/payload is different. Instead of `notification` you need to replace by `data`. You can check the differences here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: OnMessageRecieved is never called, when app is in background.

Answer (score 0):

Stacking notifications can be done with FCM, it requires a bit of changes at server side also. All this is explained over here in detail:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43913156/6157185

Answer (score -1):

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification mNotification = builder
            .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dhlone)
            .setContentTitle("DHL")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(image).bigLargeIcon(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           .setBadgeIconType(R.drawable.dhlone)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
```

//use set setAutoCancel(true). it will work