# Android FCM - How to build a default Notification for a push with notification and data payload

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM lets us send push messages with two [kinds of payload (notification and data)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages), which are handled [differently on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages):

- notification messages, which contain only notification data
- data messages, which contain only custom data
- notification+data messages, which behave differently depending on whether the app is in foreground or not

In the third case, if the app is in foreground, the message is handled by a custom `FirebaseMessagingService` subclass in `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage)`. Otherwise, the system (or, more precisely, Google Play Services), builds the push notification.

I'd like to build a notification in `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage)` that would be identical to the notification that the system would build if the push was received while the app is dead or in background, ie. taking into account the notification data received in the push (`RemoteMessage.Notification`), the defaults set in the Manifest's meta-data, etc. Is there a method in the SDK that would allow that, or maybe a third-party library, or do I have to reverse-engineer it by myself?

Comment: There is a good explanation you can go through here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43914028/1848157

Comment: @Radhey this is a very incomplete soulution. For starters, it hard-codes the Activity launched on notification click.

Comment: Say clearly what you want.

Comment: there is no way to "copy" default notification style.
so you need to provide your own notification which probably will be different from the default one...